# How do I reference third-party jar libraries into a Java project being built by TeamCity?

Tags: java, svn, netbeans, jar, teamcity

I'm using Netbeans 7.1 to develop a number of Java projects. Several of the projects reference each other, and all of them reference external third-party libraries such as Log4J, JFreeChart, etc. Now I want to run continuous integration and automated testing using TeamCity 6.5.4, but i'm new to it and having problems with my third-party Jar's.

In Netbeans I have just added each of the relevant third-party Jar files to a seperate Library, and then I include each library in the project (so i'm not referencing the Jar directly).

The projects are checked in to Subversion. In TeamCity I created one Project, with a seperate Build Configuration for each Netbeans Project (each with a different VCS root). The Netbeans projects which depend on each other, i've set up as Snapshot Dependencies in the build configuration settings. This works fine as far as I can tell

What is the best way to set up TeamCity so it can access and build the projects with all of the necessary third-party Jar's? Should I check them into a new project, and reference this in TeamCity? Should I copy the Jar's into a specific location on the build server?

I don't understand how the "add artifact dependency" should work, because it forces me to make a build configuration reference another build config, even if they do not really depend on each other.

I'm sure this is a simple problem! All help greatly appreciated :-)
Jack

Edit: I would rather not use Maven.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use maven2! TeamCity has built-in maven support. 
http://maven.apache.org/download.html
Not sure though about maven3 support. Also netbeans integrates nicely with maven http://solitarygeek.com/java/netbeans-and-maven-a-quick-start-guide

Comment: Ok so i've spent the past four days struggling with Maven, build configurations, trying to add external repositories, getting it working, breaking my Netbeans Projects, etc etc. Thanks for your help but it's far too much effort for what I want to do here